# App service azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-appservice

I have a code for autoscale for app service.
we have common code for lower and prod env.
I need to apply autoscale setting for only prod envi.
when i plan tf I'm facing error:

> Error: Insufficient profile blocks
> │
> │   on app-service\create-app-service.tf line 132, in resource
> "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "autoscale_setting":
> │  132: resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "autoscale_setting" {
> │
> │ At least 1 "profile" blocks are required.

below is my code:

fileName: create_app_service.tf

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "autoscale_setting" {
  
  name                = "${var.resource_group_name}-ui"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  target_resource_id  = azurerm_app_service_plan.app-service-plan.id

  dynamic "profile" {
    for_each  = var.auto_scaleout == true ? [1] : []
    content {
    name = "${var.resource_group_name}-ui"

    capacity {
      default = 4
      minimum = 3
      maximum = 10
    }

    rule {
      metric_trigger {
        metric_name        = "CpuPercentage"
        metric_resource_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.app-service-plan.id
        time_grain         = "PT1M"
        statistic          = "Average"
        time_window        = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation   = "Average"
        operator           = "GreaterThan"
        threshold          = 75
      }

      scale_action {
        direction = "Increase"
        type      = "ChangeCount"
        value     = "1"
        cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }

    rule {
      metric_trigger {
        metric_name        = "CpuPercentage"
        metric_resource_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.app-service-plan.id
        time_grain         = "PT1M"
        statistic          = "Average"
        time_window        = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation   = "Average"
        operator           = "LessThan"
        threshold          = 25
      }

      scale_action {
        direction = "Decrease"
        type      = "ChangeCount"
        value     = "1"
        cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }
   }
  }

  notification {
    email {
      send_to_subscription_administrator    = false
      send_to_subscription_co_administrator = false
    }
  }
}
```

variable:

```
variable "auto_scaleout" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}
```

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "autoscale_setting" {
  
  name                = "${var.resource_group_name}-ui"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  target_resource_id  = azurerm_app_service_plan.app-service-plan.id
  enabled             = var.enable_autoscale

  dynamic "profile" {
    for_each  = var.auto_scaleout == true ? [1] : []
    content {
    name = "${var.resource_group_name}-ui"
    features {}

    capacity {
      default = 4
      minimum = 3
      maximum = 10
    }

    rule {
      metric_trigger {
        metric_name        = "CpuPercentage"
        metric_resource_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.app-service-plan.id
        time_grain         = "PT1M"
        statistic          = "Average"
        time_window        = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation   = "Average"
        operator           = "GreaterThan"
        threshold          = 75
      }

      scale_action {
        direction = "Increase"
        type      = "ChangeCount"
        value     = "1"
        cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }
```

tried by adding feature{} block

Comment: Profile block is a required parameter, so it cannot be used with `dynamic` or omitted: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_autoscale_setting#profile.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Insufficient profile blocks:

As you are not giving `terraform` block, error is occurring. If you additionally add a `features` block, it will also ask for a terraform block. If not provided, it may cause an error like "***insufficient blocks***".

***Note:*** I would suggest you, add a `profile` block because `dynamic` block itself will not support.

I added all the expected blocks and ran by including a basic `default profile`  and was able to deploy it successfully.

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.99.0" //<- Provide latest version
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
        features {}

}
resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "test" {
  name                = "AutoscaleSettingnew"
  resource_group_name = "<resource_group_name>"
  location            = "EastUS"
  target_resource_id  = "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/<appserviceplan>"
 profile {
name = "defaultProfile"
capacity {
  default = 1
  minimum = 1
  maximum = 10
}
rule {
  metric_trigger {
    metric_name        = "CPUPercentage"
    metric_resource_id = "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/<appserviceplan>"
    time_grain         = "PT1M"
    statistic          = "Average"
    time_window        = "PT5M"
    time_aggregation   = "Average"
    operator           = "GreaterThan"
    threshold          = 80
  }
  scale_action {
    direction = "Increase"
    type      = "ChangeCount"
    value     = "1"
    cooldown  = "PT1M"
  }
}
rule {
  metric_trigger {
    metric_name        = "CpuPercentage"
    metric_resource_id = "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/<appserviceplan>"
    time_grain         = "PT1M"
    statistic          = "Average"
    time_window        = "PT5M"
    time_aggregation   = "Average"
    operator           = "LessThan"
    threshold          = 80
  }
  scale_action {
    direction = "Decrease"
    type      = "ChangeCount"
    value     = "1"
    cooldown  = "PT1M"
  }
}
}
}
```

***Executed*** `terraform init`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform plan`:

[image]

`terraform apply`:

[image]

***Enabled auto_scale setting in Portal:***

[image]

Refer [Argument_reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_autoscale_setting#argument-reference)